# Load graphical data even without passing the parameters through the filter (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a problem, as soon as my page is opened, the graphics come blank, because I passed the callback for the graphics data to be generated through params request

I would like, as soon as the page is opened, to make a GET of the general data, and when requested by the filter then yes load with params

Unfortunately, I do not know which logic to use

```
     mounted() {
        this.refresh()
 },
 methods: {

      refresh () {
         this.$axios.get()
         var situacao = this.situacao.map(st => st.id)
         var cliente = this.cliente.id
         var especialidade = this.especialidade.id
         var tipo = this.tipos.id
         var helpDesk = this.helpDesk.id
         var supervisor = this.supervisor.id

         var params = {
                tipo: tipo,
                situacao: situacao,
                cliente: cliente,
                helpDesk: helpDesk,
                especialidade: especialidade,
                supervisor: supervisor     
         }

         this.$axios.get("/Operacional/GetRelatorio/?" + qs.stringify( params, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' }))
         .then(res => { 
            this.prazos = res.data
            this.$refs.chart1.updateSeries([{
                name: 'NO PRAZO',
                data: [this.prazos.noPrazo, this.prazos.emDia, this.prazos.atrasadas]
             }])
          })
```

I would like to request the params only when selecting the filter, and when not, it makes a normal GET, without params, so that the graphics once the page is loaded do not remain blank

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `data()` property in the component and define a variable with default value false.

```
data () {
return {
filterApplied: false;
}
}
```

Then when selecting the filter, change the data property to `true` and on the basis of this value send the request with or without params.

Comment: I think the error is in the logic of the params, I do not know, the console gave this error when I select only one of the filters: "vendor.afd2128a.js:formatted:4519 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null "